# Jquery Ajax call return 403 status

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, session

I have a jquery Ajax call implemented for keepalive the session, this keepAlive() method will call in every 20 mins

```
    function keepAlive() {
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "KeepAliveDummy.aspx", cache: false
        });
    }
```

This call is happen when the third party contents are loaded in to the frameset,

I'm getting 403 http status (check via fiddler) on this request, 
Will this impact the end result of refresh the session time out?

Comment: http status 403 is forbidden,check whether its CORS issue

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: use   dataType and contentType in your ajax call.. may be it will helped you.

Answer (score 6):

Since your question is about handling 403 error (Will this impact the end result of refresh the session time out?) rather what 403 is.

So, handle this error, you can log or notify.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "KeepAliveDummy.aspx",
      success: function (response) {
          //session refreshed
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        if(xhr.status==403) {
            //handle error
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: This won't work because a 403 will trigger neither 'error' nor 'complete' -- it just sort of hangs. See the reference provided by Hungnh1704 below: "the server is refusing to respond". Does anyone know how to handle 403?

Answer (score 0):

about 403 :

> 403 Forbidden The request was a valid request, but the server is
>   refusing to respond to it.[2] Unlike a 401 Unauthorized response,
>   authenticating will make no difference.[2]

it needs you to authenticate (like login) first before do call ajax. 401 error requires authenticating header field when request but 403 doesn't.

check your server or contact who has responsibility for authentication.