# Ajax Call Returns 403 From Asp

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis-7, http-status-code-403

There is a classic Asp website and we have developed a handler that would be a bridge between the website and a web service. But all I get is 403(Forbidden) error. Here is my Ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.ashx',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'email': 'test@test.com',
        'name': 'test',
        'surname': 'test',
        'gsm': 'test',
        'GSM_PERMIT': 'L',
        'CALL_PERMIT': 'L',
        'EMAIL_PERMIT': 'L',
        'selectedaccounts': 'testa, testb'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

What could be the problem? Any help is appriciated, thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Ajax call return 403 status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979374/jquery-ajax-call-return-403-status)